# NSArrayM objectAtIndex: index 6 beyond bounds

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray

I am developing iOS application. Value store on Array, but when I run app, its *crashes* with array index out of bounds. Please Help and Thanks in advance..

**Code:**

```
daysOfWeek = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Monday",@"Tuesday",@"Wednesday",@"Thursday",@"Friday",@"Saturday",@"Sunday", nil];
    for (int i = 0; i<= [_daysOfWeek count]; i++) {
   _mondayView=[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(45, 300  , 830, 30.0)];
         [_mondayView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:190.0/255.0 green:190.0/255.0 blue:194.0/255.0 alpha:1.0]];
        [_weeklyView addSubview:_mondayView];

        UILabel *daysLabel = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(65.0f, 300.0f, 120.0f, 30.0f)];
        daysLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
        daysLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[_daysOfWeek objectAtIndex:i]];
        [_weeklyView addSubview:daysLabel];

    }
```

**Crash Log:**

```
2016-11-14 11:48:41.266 FH Harvey[1839:67640] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayI objectAtIndex:]: index 7 beyond bounds [0 .. 6]'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000011101934b __exceptionPreprocess + 171
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000011065d21e objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000110f53eeb -[__NSArrayI objectAtIndex:] + 155
    3   FH Harvey                           0x000000010fe1ee62 -[FHWeeklyViewController viewDidLoad] + 1026
    4   UIKit                               0x00000001115ddc99 -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 1258
    5   UIKit                               0x00000001115e4102 -[UIViewController __viewWillAppear:] + 118
    6   UIKit                               0x000000011160efbf -[UINavigationController _startCustomTransition:] + 1290
    7   UIKit                               0x000000011161fc34 -[UINavigationController _startDeferredTransitionIfNeeded:] + 697
    8   UIKit                               0x0000000111620dc7 -[UINavigationController __viewWillLayoutSubviews] + 58
    9   UIKit                               0x0000000111817d6f -[UILayoutContainerView layoutSubviews] + 223
    10  UIKit                               0x0000000111500f50 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 1237
    11  QuartzCore                          0x000000010ffbdcc4 -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 146
    12  QuartzCore                          0x000000010ffb1788 _ZN2CA5Layer16layout_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 366
    13  QuartzCore                          0x000000010ffb1606 _ZN2CA5Layer28layout_and_display_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 24
    14  QuartzCore                          0x000000010ff3f680 _ZN2CA7Context18commit_transactionEPNS_11TransactionE + 280
    15  QuartzCore                          0x000000010ff6c767 _ZN2CA11Transaction6commitEv + 475
    16  UIKit                               0x0000000111435a97 _UIApplicationFlushRunLoopCATransactionIfTooLate + 206
    17  UIKit                               0x0000000111c456e0 __handleEventQueue + 5672
    18  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000110fbe311 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17
    19  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000110fa359c __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 556
    20  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000110fa2a86 __CFRunLoopRun + 918
    21  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000110fa2494 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 420
    22  GraphicsServices                    0x00000001163a0a6f GSEventRunModal + 161
    23  UIKit                               0x000000011143c964 UIApplicationMain + 159
    24  FH Harvey                           0x000000010fe221bf main + 111
    25  libdyld.dylib                       0x000000011491368d start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is with your for loop. Array index start with `0` so change your for loop to:

```
for (int i = 0; i < [_daysOfWeek count]; i++) {
```

You are using `i<=[_daysOfWeek count]` that is the reason you are getting `index 7 beyond bounds [0 .. 6]` crash.

Instead of using `for` loop you can use `for each` loop and it easy to implement and it will never cause you index out of bound crash.

```
 for (NSString* str in _daysOfWeek) {
     NSLog(@"%@",str);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

DEEPAK kumar just verify your logic. Your array having 7 values and you are iterating it 8 times. Just change the logic

```
for (int i = 0; i < [_daysOfWeek count]; i++)
```

**or**

use `for each` loop as *Nirav D* describes (most optimized way).

Happy coding..

Answer (score 0):

Just changing you for loop logic from `i <= [_daysOfWeek count]` to `i < [_daysOfWeek count]` should resolve your problem. However, to avoid mistakes like this in future, I suggest you to use `enumerateObjectsUsingBlock` method of `NSArray`. It can be done in the following way:

```
NSArray *daysOfWeek = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Monday",@"Tuesday",@"Wednesday",@"Thursday",@"Friday",@"Saturday",@"Sunday", nil];
[daysOfWeek enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(NSString*  _Nonnull obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL * _Nonnull stop) {

}];
```

Answer (score 0):

Please write :

```
for (int i = 0; i < [_daysOfWeek count]; i++)
```

It will help you.